# I am creating a loop which goes through my data to then save it into an array to be used later for filtering purposes

Tags: excel, vba

I am automating a report, and the hierarchy is always subject to change. Since people who will be using this macro have no coding skills I have been creating a new report. But recently I got stuck on this part. I have a sheet where the user can enter the hierarchy. Then the code loops through the hierarchy added and saves it in a method that I thought would work in an array. It will run but when it gets to the filter part I get the error: The object invoked has disconnected from its clients

I originally had the hierarchy in the code before but I do not want the users to touch the code. When it was in the code It worked perfectly. The way I am doing it now appears to match what I had done before but am once again having issues

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Set wa = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Set wt = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastrow = wa.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

lastrow99 = wt.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
For Each a In wt.Range("A2:A" & lastrow99)
    If IMRCCSpec1 = Empty Then
        IMRCCSpec1 = a.Cells.Value
    Else
        IMRCCSpec1 = IMRCCSpec1 & """" & ", " & """" & a.Cells.Value
    End If
Next a
lastrow99 = wt.Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
For Each a In wt.Range("B2:B" & lastrow99)
    If IMRCCSup1 = Empty Then
        IMRCCSup1 = a.Cells.Value
    Else
        IMRCCSup1 = IMRCCSup1 & """" & ", " & """" & a.Cells.Value
    End If
Next a
IMRRCCSpec = Array(IMRCCSpec1)
IMRRCCSup = Array(IMRCCSup1)

wa.Range("A1:U" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=wa.Range("D1:D" & lastrow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
wa.Range("A1:U" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=IMRCCSpec, Operator:=xlFilterValues

End Sub
```

I would like for the the code to actually filter based on what the hierarchy is

Comment: skip the loops: `IMRRCCSpec = wt.Range("A2:A" & lastrow99).Value` and `IMRRCCSup = wt.Range("B2:B" & lastrow99).Value`

Comment: Scott thank you for the reply! I gave that a shot an was given the same error again. This is what I just tried

`lastrow99 = wt.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
IMRCCSpec1 = wt.Range("A2:A" & lastrow99).Value
IMRRCCSpec = Array(IMRCCSpec1)

wa.Range("A1:U" & lastrow).Sort Key1:=wa.Range("D1:D" & lastrow), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
wa.Range("A1:U" & lastrow).AutoFilter field:=6, Criteria1:=IMRCCSpec, Operator:=xlFilterValues`

Comment: `Array(IMRCCSpec1)` just gives you an array with a single string value.  FYI it's not clear to me what you mean by "hierarchy" here

Comment: My apologies, 
The hierarchy is just a list of departments that I need to filter by. So I am having them insert their departments into a sheet. Then the code is supposed to go row by row adding them into the variable IMRCCSpec to later be used as a filter